# Select a tab in Firefox from command line

Tags: firefox, command-line, tabs

Firefox already lets you open new URLs from the command line.  Is there a way to select an existing tab from the command line, by title or URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is:

- install [MozRepl](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/mozrepl) addon
- start it: Tools -> MozRepl -> Start
- use telnet to connect to the running MozRepl instance:

  ```
  $ telnet 127.0.0.1 4242
  ```

  You can also use `rlwrap` to enable `readline`-like keybindings inside telnet session:

  ```
  $ rlwrap telnet 127.0.0.1 4242
  ```
- define a function for searching a tab with a given URL and switching to it. This one from https://github.com/emacsmirror/cedet/blob/master/lisp/cedet/semantic/db-mozrepl.el is pretty cool:

  ```
  function semanticselecttab(url) {
       var numTabs=gBrowser.browsers.length;
       for(i=0; i<numTabs-1; i++) {
         if(gBrowser.browsers[i].contentDocument.location.href.indexOf(url)>=0) {
           gBrowser.tabContainer.selectedIndex=i;
           break;
         }
       }   
  }
  ```
- run it like this:

  ```
  repl> semanticselecttab("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055148/select-a-tab-in-firefox-from-command-line")
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately incomatible with firefox quantum